# Add parentheses to string condition

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, algorithm

I have an app in which the user can write its own condition in an input. 
The user will write some condition that gonna look something like that

```
1 AND 2 AND 3 OR (5 AND 6)
```

I need to add this condition parentheses in the same way the computer will execute the condition

```
((1 AND 2) AND 3) OR (5 AND 6)
```

What is the best algorithm for this kind of task?

Some examples:

```
1 AND 2 --> (1 AND 2)

1 AND 2 AND 3--> ((1 AND 2) AND 3)

1 AND 2 OR 3 --> ((1 AND 2) OR 3)

1 AND (2 OR 3)--> (1 AND (2 OR 3))

1 AND (2 OR 3) AND 4 --> ((1 AND (2 OR 3)) AND 4)

1 AND (2 OR 4) --> (1 AND (2 OR 4))

(1 AND 2) OR (2 OR 4) --> ((1 AND 2) OR (2 OR 4))
```

Comment: Take a look at Dijkstra's [shunting yard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) algorithm to retrieve the operators in order of precedence. You can use the algorithm to build a tree, and then to create your final string you can traverse the tree and add parentheses to your expressions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Dijkstra's [shunting yard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) algorithm, you can use the following functions, inspired by pseudocode [here](https://brilliant.org/wiki/shunting-yard-algorithm/), to wrap your expressions with parentheses in order of precedence.

Note that my earlier comment regarding building a tree was actually an unnecessary step, as you can instead work directly with the built postfix expression (although, postfix is simply a postorder traversal of the tree that would be generated, but the tree is not necessary here):

```js
const precedence = ['|', '&']; // AND has a higher precedence than OR

const buildPostfix = expression => {
  const opStack = [];
  const postfix = [];
  const replaced = expression.replace(/AND/g, '&').replace(/OR/g, '|'); // replace the words with single characters to make parsing simpler
  
  for (let c of replaced) { // iterate through characters
    if (c === ' ') continue; // disregard a space
    if (c === '(') {
      opStack.push(c);
    } else if (c == ')') {
      let op = opStack.pop();
      while (op !== '(') { // push all tokens in between a set of parentheses
        postfix.push(op);
        op = opStack.pop();
      }
    } else if (precedence.includes(c)) { // check if character is operator or number
      while (opStack.length && precedence.indexOf(opStack[opStack.length - 1]) >= precedence.indexOf(c)) { // push operators with a higher precedence first
        postfix.push(opStack.pop());
      }
      opStack.push(c); // push the current operator
    } else {
      postfix.push(c); // push the number onto the stack
    }
  }

  while (opStack.length) { // push remaining operators
    postfix.push(opStack.pop());
  }

  return postfix;
};

const addParentheses = expression => {
  const expStack = [];
  const postfix = buildPostfix(expression);

  postfix.forEach(c => {
    if (precedence.includes(c)) { // check if character is operator or number
      const right = expStack.pop(); // get right operand
      const left = expStack.pop(); // get left operand
      expStack.push(`(${left} ${c} ${right})`); // create expression in form of (<left> <op> <right>)
    } else {
      expStack.push(c); // push number on stack
    }
  });
  return expStack[0].replace(/&/g, 'AND').replace(/\|/g, 'OR'); // get the entire expression and re-substitute AND and OR for & and |, respectively
};

const expressions = [
  '1 AND 2 AND 3 OR (5 AND 6)',
  '1 AND 2',
  '1 AND 2 AND 3',
  '1 AND 2 OR 3',
  '1 AND (2 OR 3)',
  '1 AND (2 OR 3) AND 4',
  '1 AND (2 OR 4)',
  '(1 AND 2) OR (2 OR 4)'
];
const parenthesized = expressions.map(addParentheses);
parenthesized.forEach((p, i) => console.log(`${expressions[i]} --> ${p}`));
```

For reference, this is the pseudocode which describes the gist of what `buildPostfix` accomplishes:

```
While there are tokens to be read:
    Read a token
    If it's a number add it to queue
    If it's an operator:
        While there's an operator on the top of the stack with greater precedence:
            Pop operators from the stack onto the output queue
            Push the current operator onto the stack
            If it's a left bracket push it onto the stack
            If it's a right bracket:
                While there's not a left bracket at the top of the stack:
                    Pop operators from the stack onto the output queue
                Pop the left bracket from the stack and discard it

While there are operators left on the stack, pop them to the queue
```

Then, `addParentheses` simply parses this postfix expression and, starting with the operator determined to have the highest precedence, it iteratively retrieves an operator's operands from the expression and surrounds them with parentheses